# Is it possible to search for flagged comments from my account?

Tags: support

I want to search systematically for comments of mine, that were flagged for whatever reason, and remove them myself (before they're moderated, and yes: I well know moderators are still able to see them).

Usually moderators decide to remove such comments, when the flagging reason is agreed. But I have some existing comments that were (righteously) flagged, and I want to search for these systematically, and remove them to prevent potential additional flagging.

Is this possible without having moderator privileges?

Comment: No. IIRC, it's not even possible *with* moderator privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

Is there any reason you want to know about this before a mod sees them?

To my knowledge, you get no punishment for having any or all of your comments flagged.

The only way to currently stop a trouble user from posting comments is if they get suspended, and it won't be because of comment flags. It will be because of a custom flag to a moderator detailing a user's consistent abuse of the comment system and will likely end up with an account or network wide suspension for *N* period of time.

---

> that's just a hard task without getting some reasonable filter on them
> for review.

I created a [simple SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/225391/user---comments) for you, that searches for comments left by you that are less than 61 characters in length. It returned 1200+ comments. So I would start with these, since there seems to be many obsolete, not constructive types of comments that you can easily delete.

Comment: There is no punishment for comment flags, and [even no way for moderators to see major comment abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218527/raise-an-automatic-flag-for-many-deleted-comments-from-the-same-user).

Comment: _"Is there any reason you want to know about this before a mod sees them?"_ There's no way to hide from mods AFAIK as mentioned. The intend is to go for afterwork, if mods missed to remove them and I know comments must have been flagged.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ just go through your comments and delete the ones that are obsolete, rude/offensive, not constructive, or too chatty

Comment: @lostsock _"just go through your comments ..."_ Exactly! The question was, if this is somehow possible to do systematically. I've left thousands of comments over time (the majority of them being helpful as I hope), and that's just a hard task without getting some reasonable filter on them for review.

Comment: @lostsock May be you're right, and it's part of my burden to take. What the hey! I should get those 357 pages reviewed by myself :P ... And yes: This is asked in reaction for a timed account suspension.

Comment: @lostsock THX a lot. I think adapting your query sample, using my SQL skills along with a deep knowledge about my own usual _rude vocabulary_, will give me some reasonable results to work on, as soon my account is unlocked.